# Maven muliti-module problem with artifact in dependency hierarchy

Tags: maven, apache-poi, multi-module

I have a maven multi-module project. Earlier I needed Apache POI library, but now I must remove them. I removed dependency node from pom file. In parent project everything is ok, but in module pom file in dependency hierarchy POI is still visible, but it isn't visible in resolved dependencies (in eclipse IDE with m2p). How to remove POI from module project from dependency hierarchy?

I try clean cache of m2p and change updatePolicy in settings.xml, but it not resolve the problem.

Comment: Could you post pom.xml files?

Answer (score 0):

check first from the command line: `mvn dependency:tree`

To see if the dependency is brought by a component.

If you can't see it just refresh/build/clean your project in eclipse to clean any caching issues.